# How to define function to predict data in Sofmax regression

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensor

I just study about the softmax regression, and I have a question really need your help. Here, I begin with [MNIST softmax regression](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py), and in this kind problem, it only calculate the accuracy without mention how to predict data.

But my problem is different:

[My training data form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93kQh.png)

and I would like to predict the output with given input

Therefore, for my data, I define the following variables

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 3]))

b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
```

After training, I got W and b, but I don't know how to define the function to predict output if my input now is

```
x= [[11, 7],[3, 4],[1, 0]]
```

Could you help me to figure out?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The function to predict should be the same you used at training time. I do not understand the question.